# Page Navigation, goto page N, feature request

Tags: feature-request, navigation

My feature request is for the page navigation buttons that are on many of the different pages.

I would like to see, aside from the usual page buttons, a small input box and a "goto" button so that you can skip directly to a particular page.
For example on the **Tags** page, the page navigation buttons have:
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] ... [353] [next]
I would love to see:
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5] ... [353] [next]  [inputbox][goto]
That way the user can jump around the pages much quicker than only being able to skip ahead 2 pages at a time.
**Edit - added:**
Alternatively you could just have the [goto] button and then when it is clicked, have a small popup appear with the input area and another [goto] button, you can see an example of it here: http://www.diecast-pub.com/forums2/index.php?showtopic=44473, just goto the bottom and click on the button with [2 pages] on it to see the popup appear.

Comment: Would still be quite useful on the SE 2.0 sites as well.

Answer (score 15):

Real programmers edit the URL to go to specific pages. :)

Seriously though, this would be useful at times.

Comment: Yes that is how I have been doing it too. :-)

Comment: Also when you have to edit the url you have to know what to put (e.g. `?page=17`)

Comment: I was doing this just today :)

Comment: Yes, I do this too... be good to have a proper feature though

Comment: It's not easy to edit the URL on some mobile/touchscreen devices.

Comment: This is not an answer. Like with questions, I expect an answer to involve some facts that go beyond "I agree" and help solve the problem presented.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald The first sentence does address the question.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a GreaseMonkey script to do it (tested on tags, users, questions & question answers):

```
(function() {
    function GM_wait() {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
        } else { 
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
        }
    }
    GM_wait();
    function letsJQuery() {
        var pageHref = $(".pager:first a:first").attr("href");
        var $gotoBox = $("<input type='text' value='goto' />")
            .css({ "margin": 0, "padding": "0 4px", "width": "35px", "color": "#CCC", "font-size": "130%"})
            .appendTo($(".pager"))
            .keypress(function(e) {
                if (e.which == 13)
                    window.location = pageHref.replace(/page=[0-9]+/, "page=" + $(this).val());
            })
            .focus(function() { $(this).val('').css('color', '#808185'); })
            .blur(function() { $(this).val('goto').css('color', '#CCC'); });
    }
})();
```

So, now next to the <kbd>next</kbd> link, there should be a `[goto]` text box. Just enter a number, hit enter & voila.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to edit URLs on some touchscreen and mobile devices. A button generating a 'goto page #' prompt would be very useful.

Rather than having a new button (which could potentially clutter the interface), how about generating the 'goto page' prompt by clicking on the existing ellipsis (…)? I remember being able to do this on another site, which is what caused me to discover that I can't on SE.

*Note: I originally had posted this as [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121949/166957) which was closed as a duplicate for this one.*

Answer (score 2):

As Series8217 [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121953/145914), text entry can be fiddly on touchscreen devices, so another alternative is to have 100-page jump buttons*.

When currently on page 1:

> **[1]** [2] [3] [4] [5] … [101] … [5195] next

When currently on page 243 (who ever goes that deep?):

> prev [1] … [143] … [241] [242] **[243]** [244] [245] … [343] … [5195] next

---

*Real programmers don't use touchscreens.

Comment: * - You mean you don't browse SO while driving? Err...

Comment: This is the best idea, but I wish the whole question had received more support.