# Why can't I Jump to a Page Directly?

Tags: feature-request

If there are total 500 pages, and i have to see some content on page no. 250 , i should be able to jump to that direct, using Next <> Prev is annoying

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12330/page-navigation-goto-page-n-feature-request

Comment: Not to be too glib, but what would you be looking for on page 250? It may be better to answer *that* question so the developers can find/implement a better searching mechanism to solve *that* problem rather than implementing an esoteric "jump to page" function.

Comment: Can't speak for the OP, but I occasionally want to look at questions which might net me a necromancer badge, so go to the unanswered:newest view, and then jump to 100, 500, 1000, 750, ... in search of the 60 day mark. (Which is made harder, because you have to open questions to find out when they were asked, rather than the time of last activity...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all else fails, you can just edit the url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%2b%2b&page=5&sort=newest&pagesize=50
                                                            ^ here
```

Comment: Try doing that with a small touchscreen..

Answer (score 3):

Well, not ideal - but depending on the user you can always edit the url:

[page 100 of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%23&page=100&sort=newest&pagesize=50) - note the `&page=100`