# No longer possible to jump to a specific page of questions on SO

Tags: discussion, new-nav

SO appears to have change recently, with respect to the questions page. It may be to do with the "new" tab functionality, I am not sure.

Previously, it was possible to order the questions by "Newest" and then after having jumped to page 2, then one could directly manipulate the `page` parameter in the URL, as described in [Why can't I Jump to a Page Directly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23735/why-cant-i-jump-to-a-page-directly), like so:

```
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions?page=5&sort=newest
```

However, now, on SO, it seems that is no longer possible, as irrespective of which page one is on, the URL is always

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions
```

One can only select the pages offered at the bottom of the page:

[image: Page selector]

If I am trying to get to the page for questions in January, for example, how can I do that, without having to repeatedly scroll to the bottom and selecting only two pages along from where I already am?

If I am missing something then I apologise.

Other sites still behave as before - this new behaviour only appears to be on SO.

Comment: Have you checked M.SE to see if it happens here too? If memory serves, new-nav is being tested here as well.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - It works as before on Meta. The new functionality doesn't appear to have been implemented on Meta - yet...

Comment: Oh, did you check to make sure you're opted into the new-nav test here? I thought they were synced but maybe not.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I have just checked and I do appear to have opted in (probably for quite some time now, as I can't remember clicking on it recently). Is this opt-in checkbox site specific or SE wide? I presumed that it was SE wide.

Comment: New Navigation seems to be set per-site because I see it on my Profile for [so] and [meta.se] but not for [genealogy.se] or [gis.se].

Comment: @PolyGeo - My opt-in is set for both Meta and SO, but there is no such option available on Raspberry Pi, nor on SuperUser, nor ServerFault. It must only be available for certain sites.

Comment: My "not set" for the other two sites is because it is not available there as a checkbox too.  I am thinking this issue is [so] specific and not directly related to the New Navigation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is still possible, you just have to type (or paste) a little more than the page number you want.

If you append the page parameter to the end of the url, you're taken to that page in the list. The url will revert to what it shows now, but you won't have your page changed back.

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=5 still takes you to page five of the Stack Overflow questions, the url will just change back to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions` once there.

*However,* if you were to refresh on page five, you will be taken back to page one. [This is apparently intentional.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312524/2607247) (Check the comments of that answer for the details exchange.) If you want to remain on that page, I recommend copying your modified url and pasting it rather than refreshing. It's obnoxious, but how we currently need to work around this.

The above is all true for (M)SO, but not for MSE.

Answer (score 0):

This works on three Stack Exchange sites that I tested:

- https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions?page=4&sort=newest
- https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions?page=99&sort=newest
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?page=22&sort=newest

so the issue you are encountering, that I can reproduce, seems to be Stack Overflow specific, or at least not Stack Exchange network-wide.

In case it is relevant I opted into the New Navigation for Meta Stack Exchange quite a while ago:

[image]

I am also using the New Navigation on Stack Overflow so I think this issue is unrelated to the New Navigation.

Comment: Yes, it is only on SO. All of the other sites appear to be unaffected. The change seems to be a new feature, possibly being tested on SO. Sorry, I should have made that point clearer in my post. I shall update.

Comment: I think that should mean migration of your question to [meta.so] will be appropriate.

Comment: I can see your point. However, I assumed that if it has been rolled out on SO, then it _may_ in future be rolled out to all sites, as many new features appear to be "beta'd" (as it were) on SO first. Hence why I posted it on Meta, rather than SO meta.

Comment: I'm used to asking questions on Beta software using Beta discussion forums. [so] probably won't like being termed a forum (because it's not) but I do think the place to address this is through its per site Meta rather than this network-wide one.

Comment: Isn't the new-nav SO and M.SE specific?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm not sure about the new-nav but this issue does not appear here at [meta.se] - try http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?page=5&sort=newest

Comment: @NathanTuggy It seems to be unrelated to the New Navigation because I have opted into that on both [meta.se] and [so].