# Year/Month drop down menu for questions sortest by "Newest"

Tags: feature-request, sorting

Following on from [No longer possible to jump to a specific page of questions on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278062/no-longer-possible-to-jump-to-a-specific-page-of-questions-on-so), would it not be a good idea to add a more user friendly method of selection ranges of chronologically ordered questions?

As it stands, from [Why can't I Jump to a Page Directly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23735/why-cant-i-jump-to-a-page-directly), it is necessary to directly manipulate the `page` parameter in the URL, like so:

```
http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions?page=5&sort=newest
```

Now, not all of the users of *certain* SE sites are developers, or IT professionals, and may find playing about with URL parameters somewhat daunting.

As I stated in [No longer possible to jump to a specific page of questions on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278062/no-longer-possible-to-jump-to-a-specific-page-of-questions-on-s), trying to get back to a certain set of dates using the page selector at the bottom of the screen,

[image: Page selector]

is not particularly efficient.

Thus, it could be a good idea to have an additional menu for chronologically ordered questions, i.e. when the "Newest" tab is selected, which provides for Years/Months to look at, similar to the menu that Facebook has:

[image: Chronological menu]

---

Why would I want to look for a question in a certain month or a certain year?

Because, to take one concrete example, I found a question on Raspberry Pi, where the user said that they had previously asked the exact same question on SO, and had got no reply. I then looked at the date of the question on RPi, which was late January (2016), and searched chronologically for questions on SO, from late January and before, until I found it, and flagged it as having been subsequently asked and answered on a different SE site.

Using the `page` parameter made this easier than repeatedly scrolling down and selecting two pages back into history. However, it would have been even simpler to have selected a month from a drop down menu. In addition, should the new navigation UI currently being tested on SO if rolled out, then the use of the `page` parameter will be further complicated as the `page` parameter will no longer be shown in the URL (see [The new nav pagination links are broken on the homepage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312499/the-new-nav-pagination-links-are-broken-on-the-homepage/312524#312524)).

OK, this may be a bit of an edge case, but I have found other reasons to look back for historical questions, which were referred to, in another question, but no link was provided, just a vague description and (maybe) a date.

Comment: Why not implement an interactive calendar to select more specific time frames?

Comment: So you're essentially asking for a limited GUI for the `created:` search parameter?

Comment: @arjafi - Possibly, although I have never heard of the `created:` parameter... where is it listed? It doesn't appear under the `Advanced Search Tips` on the search page. However, rather than using the search page, I thought about have it in a more prominent location on the standard questions page, when the `Newest` tab is selected - It would seem to be a logical place for it.

Comment: @Greenonline It's listed in the Help Center's [How do I search? page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching). (I'm actually surprised it's not in the Advanced Search Tips.)