# Clicking the ellipsis between page numbers should prompt for a page number

Tags: feature-request, navigation, pagination

It's pretty hard to get to page 500 when the navigation tool looks like this:
`1 2 3 4 5 … 3896 next`

If clicking the ellipsis (`…`) produced a prompt allowing users to type in the desired page, that would be awesome.

Editing the URL is not easy on small touchscreens. It's hard to click on the right character position in the URL.

**EDIT:** Since this was closed as a duplicate for another question, I added my suggestion as an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121953/166957) over there.

Comment: That's not a bad idea but it does raise the question of discovery, since no one else seems to do it. Maybe SE could establish the idiom

Comment: Just edit the URL, same thing.

Comment: What about when there are two ellipsis? Does the second one open a portal to the magical land of unicorns? `prev 1 … 3 4 5 6 7 … 52766 next` Also, you can just type `?page=##` into the URL if you want.

Comment: @Conrad I've used it on another site, but I don't remember where. That's how I discovered that SE doesn't do it.

Comment: @animuson What's wrong with just doing the same thing? It's not like any of the ellipsis do anything right now anyway.

Comment: @Matthew It's hard to edit URLs on some touchscreen and mobile devices.

Comment: A simpler idea perhaps would be to add buttons to jump forwards or backwards 100 pages at a time. `1 2 3 4 5 ... 100 ... 3896 next`

Comment: I realize this is a slightly different take on the older request, but the core is still the same. Feel free to propose this as a suggestion in an edit or an answer on that other request.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman that certainly fixes the discovery problem (which URL Editing has the same problem)