# Adding a search bar for page numbers

Tags: feature-request, search, hyperlinks

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but could we have a search bar next to the page numbers so that we can easily find the nth page? For example, there are 740 pages in Meta SE unanswered, so it would be difficult to find the 100th page without changing the URL manually. It would be great to have this additional feature, perhaps next to the 'next' button?

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As well as: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12330/162011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, just modify the URL manually. When you click on page 5, the URL shows e.g.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?page=5&sort=newest

or

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser/2018-08-26?sort=reputationchange&page=5

and you can easily change the 5 into another number.

TBH, I just don't see any situations where you would use this. If you know a certain post is on page 39 of the list, you can navigate to it directly; if you are viewing a list of questions in chronological order and want to jump quickly to the questions from 2015, just use the [Advanced Search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

Comment: I mentioned URL already in my post. To give a more interesting example, searching user leagues.

Comment: Right. I'm just leaving it in case other users don't know what we mean. Note that the user leagues have a similar paging structure.

Answer (score 0):

But what would be the *point* of going to page X specifically?

There's no inherently significant information derived from a question being on page 57 of the question list. The actually important information is *what* the order derives from, like its age, its score, whatever else you can sort by. And for that you have better search options already. But going to a specific page doesn't seem to be a meaningful action.

Instead of trying to guess the mysteries of what questions land on what page and maneuvre to that, just improve your search and look for what you *really* want to know.